# creating own "charcopy" function using pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

I am trying to create my own char copy (like strcopy) function. **It needs to be custom**, I cannot use the one inside the std lib (Strcopy). I **cannot change my char arrays to strings**. I **cannot use built in functions to copy the chars.** **i must use pointers to manipulate the array**

I am trying to work off what the *real* strcopy looks like, but i cant seem toget mine to work. I **THINK** I want to create a pointer that points to strcpy(char *destination*,char source) and then I manipulate destination through source but nothing is copying over correctly and I just print out garbage. Please help open to all suggestions

```
void StrCpy(char *destination, char *source);

int main()
{
card card1[10], card2[10];
card1[0].cvalue = 1000;
card2[0].cvalue = 90000;
card *card1p = &card1[0];
card *card2p = &card2[0];
//set up card file to be read in
ifstream fin;
string finName;

//get file name from user
cout << "Enter file name...(cardFile.txt)" << endl;;
getline(cin,finName);


//open the file
fin.open(finName.c_str());


//check if cardFile.txt opens correctly
if(!fin.good())
{
    cout << "Error with card file" << endl;
    return 0;
}
else
{
    card *deckPointer = NULL;

    //prime fin
    //fin >> deck[i].suit;
    //fin >> deck[i].rank;
    //fin >> deck[i].cvalue;

    while(fin.good())
    {
    for(card1p = &card1[0]; card1p < &card1[10];card1p++)
        {
            fin >> (*card1p).suit;
            fin >> (*card1p).rank;
            fin >> (*card1p).cvalue;
        }   
    }    
}            
StrCpy((*card2p).suit, (*card1p).suit);
cout << (*card2).suit << endl;

}

void StrCpy(char *destination,char *source)
             {
             char *p = destination;
             *p = *source;


             }
```

Comment: It is unfortunate you have these restrictions, because this is not how you would do this in modern C++. Also note, one would generally use `card1p->suit` in place of `(*card1p).suit`. `->` is the normal syntax for accessing members and methods of a pointer to a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually the function is defined the following way

```
char * StrCpy( char *destination, const char *source )
{
    char *p = destination;

    while ( *p++ = *source++ );

    return destination;
}
```

Yet another realization

```
char * StrCpy( char *destination, const char *source )
{
    char *p = destination;

    do
    {
        *p++ = *source;   
    } while ( *source++ );

    return destination;
}
```

And one more

```
char * StrCpy( char *destination, const char *source )
{
    for ( char *p = destination; *p = *source; ++p, ++source );

    return destination;
}
```

or

```
char * StrCpy( char *destination, const char *source )
{
    char *p = destination;

    while ( *p = *source ) ++p, ++source;

    return destination;
}
```

Comment: i said going off it, and i cant use this. can you help me

Comment: @matt mowris i do not understand why you can not use it.

Comment: because i have to create my own function in liue of using the bult in strcopy

Comment: @VladfromMoscow don't you need an increment somewhere?

Comment: @matt mowris  it will be your own function. What is the problem?

Comment: it has to be different than the one that is built in

Comment: @matt mowris You can select any that you like more than others.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Don't do people's homework for them.

Comment: @Zack I will decide myself what to do and what not to do.

Comment: @mattmowris one thing with programming: there are generally not that many ways of doing a "simple" operation, such as copying a string. Here, Vlad has basically the same code, just with a slightly different loop construct. If you do it right, it *will* be somewhat like the library function.

Comment: @Zack ive been struggling with this for hours, im very new to c++ and the way my teacher is having me implement things is beyond ridiclous. im in a c++ class, not a c course.

Comment: "give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime"
Here we help people. If you do their homework, @VladfromMoscow, you are not helping them.

Comment: @mattmowris _"it has to be different than the one that is built in"_ - You should immediately go to the admin office of whatever school you are attending and get a refund.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow thank you a lot, this helps me understand exactly what strcopy does

Comment: @CaptainObvlious yea i come from an EE background and im interested in getting a MSCS but im missing data structures and its pre req.. the way this teacher is going about teaching this course is ridiculous

Answer (score 0):

```
void StrCpy(char *destination,char *source)
{
    char *p = destination;
    *p = *source;

}
```

is not correct. Basically you're doing
`destination[0] = source[0]`, which is not a actual copy.

You should read up on pointers. And formatting. And `std::string`.

Comment: but this copy is not even copying the first "H" for example. i cant use string man. can you help me

Comment: That's what it does. Tip: you need to use a loop.